# How to implement an application to take image from appropriate folder?

Tags: android, screen, android-screen-support

i am working on an android app. as this should be all screen size supportive .but it is not working properly.
I can I set that for 480*800 size it will take images from drawable-hdpi folder?

Answer (score 0):

Screen size and dpi aren't the same thing.  DPI is the number of pixels per inch.  a 480x800 screen can still be any dpi level-  it would just be a smaller screen with higher dpi.

You can try doing a size override with drawable-swNdp  where N is a pixel value.  That works for layouts, I believe it also works for drawables.

Comment: can you please give some example.

Answer (score 0):

To support on all resolution devices put different resolutions images in different folders in drawable as,
drawable-ldpi - 240 * 380 
drawable-mdpi - 320 * 480
drawable-hdpi - 480 * 800
drawable-xhdpi - 720 * 960
For more info about resolution refer this link : 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: showing error while creating folder with name drawable-hdpi-480*800.